# In an auto scaling group make sure atleast one ec2 instance is always available in a given availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have a situation to have a healthy ec2 instance running all the time in a particular availability zone.

Is there an option in ec2 auto scaling group to make sure a given availability zone (let's say ap-southeast-2b) always contains atleast one healthy ec2 instance during scale-in and scale-out ?

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

When Auto Scaling **launches a new instance**, it attempts to balance the Availability Zones. Therefore, it will launch a new instance in an AZ that has the fewest number of instances from the Auto Scaling group. If they all contain the same quantity, the AZ will be chosen randomly.

When Auto Scaling **terminates an instance** due to a scale-in policy, it first selects the AZ with the most number of running instances from the Auto Scaling group. It will then terminate an instance in that AZ. If all AZs have the same number of instances, then an AZ will be chosen randomly.

Within the chosen AZ, it will select an instance to terminate based on the **Termination Policy**. See: [Controlling Which Auto Scaling Instances Terminate During Scale In - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html)

If you want to make sure that "at least one EC2 instance is always available in a given AZ", then you would need to ensure that there are sufficient instances in the Auto Scaling group to cover **all** configured AZs. For example, if two AZs have been configured for the Auto Scaling group, then set the minimum size of the group to `2`. This will ensure that both AZs have instances.

There is also [Instance Scale-In Protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#instance-protection) that can mark an instance as 'protected', so that it is not terminated. However, this is not necessarily suitable for your situation because the instance would need to be marked whenever it is replaced. It is intended for use in very specific circumstances.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Two AZs are sufficient for High Availability. The general rule is "Don't have one of something."